# Restar valor de una tabla al agregar otra?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta estructura de datos:

Producto:

```
IDProducto 
IDCategoria
IDAlmacen
ProductoNombre
Costo
Precio
Stock
```

Venta:

```
IDVenta
IDCliente
NumFactura
FechaCarga
FechaCancela
Estado
Total
```

Ventadetalle:

```
IDVentaDetalle
VentaID
IDProducto
Precio
Cantidad
Descuento
SubTotal
```

Necesito que al ingresar en la tabla Ventadetalle, en el campo Cantidad haga la resta en el campo Stock de la tabla Producto
Luego agregue el detalle del SubTotal de Ventas y cópielo en Total de la tabla Venta.
Como puedo realizar un trigger con este resultado?

Comment: Buenas, por favor muestra el codigo donde estas haciendo lo que dices, y puedes dar formato de tabla a las cosas, solo usa la ayuda de edicion para ver como.

Comment: Deja más detalles en tu [primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470133/extraer-el-valor-de-un-campo-de-una-tabla-sobre-otro-campo-de-otra-tabla), no es necesario realizar otra. Si incluyes más detalles te podemos apoyar.

Comment: Laravel me pidieron q mediante controller una funcion beforeAdd pero no puedo:
function add(VentadetalleAddRequest $request){
    $postdata = $request->all();
    $records = [];
    foreach($postdata as &$modeldata){
      $this->beforeAdd($modeldata);
      $record = Ventadetalle::create($modeldata);
      $records[] = $record;
    }
    return $this->respond($records);
  }
  $params = ['IDProducto' => $modeldata['IDProducto'], 'Cantidad' => $modeldata['Cantidad']];
        $results = DB::select("UPDATE Producto SET Stock = Stock-Cantidad WHERE IDProducto = :IDProducto", $params);

Comment: Edita la pregunta...

Comment: Estaba leyendo que quizas estos procesos es mejor siempre hacerlos mediante triggers. Quizas, esto sea la mejor solucion y tenga que aprender a usar triggers y procedures...